# Angular 6 - Create Modules dynamically at runtime with AOT compilation

Tags: angular

I am trying to load create module dynamically and add them to route via `loadChildren`. The main reason for this approach is driven by the fact that routes config should be loaded from a `json` file.

So I have `canActivate` guard that is responsible for creating the module

```
loadFeatureModule(loadChildren: string): Observable<Type<any>> {

  this.getRoutes(loadChildren).pipe(
    switchMap(({ routes }) => {
      const featureModule = NgModule({
        imports: [
          RouterModule.forChild(routes)
        ]
      })(class { });
      return this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(featureModule);
    }),
    map(m => m.moduleType)
  );
}
```

and add feature modules to the route:

```
addFeatureModule = (loadChildren: string, path: string): Partial<Route> => {
  return {
    path: path,
    loadChildren: this.loadFeatureModule(loadChildren)
  };
}
```

And at the very end, the I reset the router config with the new routes. This works fine with JIT compiler but it won't load any of the routes with the AOT compiler.

I have also tried to inject the JitComplier to the application by introducing these new providers:

```
providers: [
  { provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true },
  { provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS] },
  { provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory] }
]

export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}
```

### Update

Please use this [repo](https://github.com/nikrooz/dynamic-module) to reproduce the problem

#### Problems

After further investigations I have identified 2 problems:

1. `AOT` and `buildOptimizer` remove the angular decorators like `NgModule` and `Component` which is needed for compiling dynamic modules. Apparently there is no solution for `buildOptimizer` and I found this nasty [hack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9306#issuecomment-361419295) for `AOT`, but is there a better solution for this?
2. When creating a module dynamically the `templateUrl` of any components declared directly/indirectly in the dynamic module cannot be loaded. In my example, this means I cannot import `LayoutModule` in to the dynamic module, as it declares a component that uses `templateUrl`.This is caused by the fact that `ResourceLoader` has been provided when compiled the application using `AOT`.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproduction as a clean github repo?

Comment: @yurzui thanks for looking at this, I have add a repo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did this get fixed?